# how to detect "â€‹" (combination of unicode) in c++ string

Tags: html, c++, string, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to detect some of the combination of Unicode character (like â€‹) to cleanup the string, For a single Unicode character it is detecting but combination of Unicode is not detecting.

These string I am using to make HTML page from another HTML page which need to be cleanup. I want to clean only string which have these kind of unicode that not even visible in html page in browser.

below is the sample code:

```
void detect_Unicode(string& str) { 

      if(!str.empty() && str.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\r\f\v\u00A0\u00C2\u00E2\u20AC\u2039")==string::npos)
                str.assign(" ");
      return;
 }
```

Input string:

```
1. " â€‹    â€‹ " ;
2. "are Â Â there is something Â Â Â â€‹ combination    â€‹"  
3. " Â Â "   
4. "â€‹  Â Â â€‹" 
5 . "Â Â â â"
```

Expected Output:

```
1. " "  
2. "are Â Â there is something Â Â Â â€‹ combination    â€‹"   
3. " "  
4. " "  
5. " "
```

Please let me know other ways too.

Comment: If you can, use `std::wstring`

Comment: `std::string` doesn't contain unicode character but "encoded" byte (possibly utf-8). so for multibyte character, you have to use `std::search` instead of `find_first_not_of`.

Comment: @PaulSanders: `wchar` is not guarantied to be 2, even in that case, unicode might need several `wchar`s.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you explain how I can use `std::search` with `string`

Comment: @Jarod452 _wchar is not guaranteed to be 2_ I don't think I ever claimed that it was.

Comment: @HarshGiri What's in the input string?  Is it a UTF-8 string?  Tell me that and I'll see if I can come up with something for you.

Comment: @PaulSanders: So why using `std::wstring` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Let's wait until we hear back from the OP and then I'll post something.

Comment: @PaulSanders  basically the string contain data of table from  different htmlpage, I am not sure how I can dentify if it UTF8 or not, But I am sure it is not always UTF-8, can be UTF-16 or ISO-8859-1

Comment: @HarshGiri OK, I'll run with that, back soon.

Comment: @Jarod42 Answer posted, ought to work.

Comment: @EricLeschinski _you should find a unicode conversion library_ To convert what to what?

Comment: @HarshGiri If you don't know, or cannot determine (using HTML and/or HTTP rules), the character encoding, you have data loss. Are you sure you can't bring this under control?

Answer (score 2):

OK, following on from the comments above, I think it's highly likely that the input string is in UTF-8 (after all, in an HTML context, what else would it be?).

On that basis, I humbly submit this:

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

std::string narrow (const std::wstring& ws)
{
    std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8 <wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes (ws);
}

std::wstring widen (const std::string& s)
{
    std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8 <wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    return convert.from_bytes (s);
}

std::string detect_Unicode (const std::string& s)
{ 
    std::wstring ws = widen (s);
    if (ws.empty() || ws.find_first_not_of (L" \t\n\r\f\v\u00A0\u00C2\u00E2\u20AC\u2039") != std::wstring::npos)
        return " ";
    return s;
}

#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << narrow (L"\u00A0 \u00C2 \u00E2 \u20AC \u2039\n\n");
    std::cout << "0.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8"abcde") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "1.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8" â€‹    â€‹ ") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "2.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8"are Â Â there is something Â Â Â â€‹ combination    â€‹") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "3.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8" Â Â ") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "4.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8"â€‹  Â Â â€‹") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "5.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8"Â Â â â") << "\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
  Â â € ‹

0.  " "
1.  " â€‹    â€‹ "
2.  " "
3.  " Â Â "
4.  "â€‹  Â Â â€‹"
5.  "Â Â â â"
```

Now this is not the output the OP expects, but I think that's simply because the *logic* (as opposed to the implementation) of `detect_Unicode()` looks flawed.  The point here is that converting the input string to a wide string means that you can use standard `basic_string` operations on it reliably, because there are no multibyte issues now.

An alternative, slightly radical, implementation of `detect_Unicode()` might be:

```
for (auto wide_char : ws)
{
    if (wide_char > 0xff)
        return " ";
}
return s;
```

But really, now you have a wide string to hand in `detect_Unicode`, anything is possible, so go wild OP.

Other notes:

- `std::codecvt` is deprecated in C++17, but since there is no other obvious choice you might as well run with it. You can always change the implementations of `narrow` and `widen` if it comes to it.
- Depending on platform, `std::wstring` might not be the best choice but it's probably fine.  You could also look at `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z6I2YQmb95ZVuKex).

Inspiration taken from [here](https://ryanclouser.com/2016/08/11/C-11-Convert-to-from-UTF-8-wchar-t/).

Comment: This seems good to me but It is not handling all the case like the input `std::cout << "1.\t\"" << detect_Unicode (u8" â€‹    â€‹ ") << "\"\n";` its output should be `1.  " "`

Comment: other case like that are handled by your code can be done simply by this condition `if(!str.empty() && str.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\r\f\v\u00A0\u00C2\u00E2\u20AC\u2039")==string::npos)
    str.assign(" ");`

Comment: _...its output should be 1. " "_ Why? _... can be done simply by this condition_ How does that improve things?

Comment: In your live demo it works as expected but for my string didnot worked as expected, seems my string is not UTF8.

Comment: this "â€‹" is not detecting for me.

Comment: @HarshGiri I think you need to set up some simple test to see if `widen` and `narrow` are actually doing what I claim they do.  They _should_ be, I can't believe that `std::codecvt` is broken.