# I have this unicodestring "Param�tres",the è is converted into unknown char.why?

Tags: c++

Tried snippets:

```
wchar_t txt = L"Hello world";
std::wstring ws(txt);
std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

Comment: Is the problem in the code, or is it a problem with the terminal or output window that can't display the character? Also note that wide characters do not imply Unicode in any way.

Comment: Looks like wide chars are getting cut in half and placed into 8 bit chars. Might I suggest [only working with chars](http://utf8everywhere.org/)?

Comment: How are you doing this `wchar_t txt = L"Hello world";` ? Does this compile even? I mean, call me a n00b but shouldn't it be `const wchar_t* txt = L"Hèllo world";`. Not that, it matters vis-à-vis the OP's main problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but thrre are some routines to convert wide strings to and from UTF-8 that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212415/5743288.  Otherwise, please clarify your question.  What, for example, is `CatUnicodeString ()`?

Comment: The purpose of � is to indicate to our users that we have mishandled their text and lost some it. Since you see it, you can go back and fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end())` simply copies each `wchar_t` *as-is*, narrowing each one to a `char`, truncating off the unused bits. This is not what you want to do, as it will only work without data loss for ASCII characters.

You need to *convert* the `wchar_t` data from UTF-16/32 (depending on what your compiler uses for encoding `wchar_t` data) to whatever charset you want the `std::string` to hold (ANSI/MBCS, UTF-8, ISO-8869-X, etc).

The C++ standard library has *minimal* built-in support for such conversions ([`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), [`std::wcstombs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs), etc), so you may have to resort to 3rd party Unicode libraries (ICONV, ICU, etc) or platform-specific APIs (`WideCharToMultiByte()`, etc).

Since you want to not only convert Unicode strings, but also compare them, then using a 3rd party Unicode library is probably going to be your best bet.  Unicode is not trivial to work with, so leverage the hard work that has already been done for it.