# C++ how to support non-ASCII characters in filesystem paths need to support paths with wide characters on all target OS's - Windows, Linux, Mac

Tags: c++, unicode, filepath

How to support non-ASCII characters in filesystem path. Need to support paths with wide characters on all target OS's - Windows, Linux, Mac.

Comment: Short answer: use `std::wstring` everywhere.  What specific problem are you trying to solve?  Is it a conversion issue between character encodings on different APIs and platforms?  I can give a lot better guidance  with respect to platform APIs, string encodings, and conversions if you can elaborate on the problem.

Comment: Cross platform handling of encodings is hard in C++ and you probably need to use a library. You can use, for example, the new Boost.Nowide library, which is designed for the exact problem you describe.

Comment: I am using Lua and need to pass file path 

const char *lua_pushlstring (lua_State *L, const char *s, size_t len);

in the end it should be const char*.

Comment: Is Lua expecting the string as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, it has basic UTF-8 support.

Comment: OK, well, there are some routines to convert between `std::wstring` and UTF-8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210723/how-to-detect-%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-combination-of-unicode-in-c-string/51212415#51212415),if that's of any help.